# Объясните как синхронизировать две таблицы

Tags: база-данных

Используй Python, но тут в языке не суть.
Есть две идентичные по структуре таблицы:

```
+-----+-------+------------+
|ID   |Name   |  Company   |
+--------------------------+
|1    | Dmitry|RKS         |
|2    | Petr  |HTD         |
|3    | Misha |CHPU        |
+-----+-------+------------+
```

В каждую из них могут добавить руками новую запись. Как будет выглядеть алгоритм проверки и переноса новой записи из одной таблицы в другую. Мне говорили, что нужно добавить еще один ID и как-то его использовать, но я не совсем понял

Answer (score 1):

1. Считать одну запись из БД1
2. Добавить эту запись в БД2
3. Если в Бд2 успешно записалось удалить запись в Бд1, если нет перейти в пункт 1
4. Проверить успешность удаления
5. Перейти в пункт1